# Listivew with binding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I've got a listview with binding and it's not updating. Can somebody find the bug? Wish I had some money, because I would offer a reward.

In this screen cap, the window on the right (Active Dinosaur List) is NOT updating when the status of a particular dinosaur is changing (note that when you click on the dinosaur (in this case, Nancy) it shows, correctly, that her status is, "Moving to food" while the Active Dinosaur List is showing her still Resting:

[image]

Here's all the relevant code, starting with the XAML for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="DinosaurIsland.ActiveDinosaurList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DinosaurIsland" 

    Title="ActiveDinosaurList" Height="850" Width="245" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"  Icon="/DinosaurIsland;component/Icon1.ico"  ResizeMode="NoResize"   >
<Window.Resources>
    <local:EnergyBarColorConverter x:Key="EnergyBarColorConverter"/>
    <local:DinoStatusConverter x:Key="DinoStatusConverter"/>


    <DataTemplate x:Key="DinosaurInfo">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <Label Name="DinosaurName"  Margin="0,0,0,-8" Content="{Binding Path=PersonalName}"/>
            <Label Name="DinosaurSpecies" Margin="0,0,0,-8" FontStyle="Italic" Content="{Binding Path=Specie}"/>
            <Label Name="DinosaurStatus" Margin="0,0,0,-8" Content="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource DinoStatusConverter}}"/>
            <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,-2" Content="Energy" />
            <ProgressBar  Name="Health" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="15"  
                          Foreground ="{Binding Path=Health, Converter={StaticResource EnergyBarColorConverter}}"  Value="{Binding Path=Health}"  />
            <Separator/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Width="210">
    <ListView x:Name="DinoListView"  Width="207" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Dinosaurs}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,0,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Select Dinosaur"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource DinosaurInfo}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Here's the Dinosaur class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DinosaurIsland 
{
public class Dinosaur : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _specie;
    public string Specie
        {
        get { return _specie; }
        set{_specie = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Specie");}
        }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public int _health;
    public int Health 
        {
        get { return _health; }
        set{_health = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Health");}
        }
    public double Water { get; set; }
    public double FoodConsumed { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }
    public string PersonalName { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Point Head = new System.Windows.Point();
    public List<System.Windows.Point> Location { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public byte _state;
    public byte State             
        {
        get { return _state; }
        set{_state = value; RaisePropertyChanged("State");}
        }
    public System.Windows.Point Goal = new System.Windows.Point();

    public System.Windows.Point[] FoodLocation = new System.Windows.Point[5]; // The last five locations that the dino found food
    public System.Windows.Point[] WaterLocation = new System.Windows.Point[5]; // The last five locations that the dino found water

    // Constructor
    public Dinosaur()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    //called when a property is changed
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's the ViewModel class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DinosaurIsland
{
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
       this.Dinosaurs = new ObservableCollection<Dinosaur>();
       for(int i = 0; i < MainWindow.Dinosaurs.Count; i++)

           this.Dinosaurs.Add(new Dinosaur()
        {
            PersonalName = MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].PersonalName,
            Specie = MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Specie,
            Health =  MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Health,
            State =  MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].State
        });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    //called when a property is changed
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Dinosaur> _dinoList = new ObservableCollection<Dinosaur>();
    public ObservableCollection<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs
    {
        get { return _dinoList; }
        set { _dinoList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Dinosaurs"); }
    }
}
```

}

Here's how the window is invoked:

```
// This is a global        
public ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

// ....

// Instantiate window
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
DinoListDialogBox.DataContext = vm;
DinoListDialogBox.Show();
```

That should be all the pieces to the puzzle. What am I missing?

Thanks... and I'll name a dinosaur after you.

Comment: In your ViewModel what's MainWindow that you seem to access and create the Dinosaurs property from? If you're changes are just made to the dinosaurs property item in MainWindow it's not going to update the items in dinosaurs property of your ViewModel since its a value copy on creation and there does not seem to be any events to keep them in sync based on property changes of source. Why do you even have a property in your MainWindow and your ViewModel. Just have one collection and have both classes access the same list(Model)

Comment: Dinosaurs are used all over the place. This is the global where they are created:          public static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosaur>(); Then there's a XML file which from which the list is populated.

Comment: Can I rewrite this so ViewModel is linked to the Dinosaurs list directly and not a copy?

Comment: Couple of questions (before I run off an play a gig): 1) how would I make <List> Dinosaur a property and not a simple variable  - i don't understand the terms in this context? and 2) how would I set it up so that when new dinosaurs are created (or die) and the <List> Dinosaur is updated it is reflected in Active Dinosaur List?

Comment: I'm sorry for being so dense, but are you suggesting ' public static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs { get; set; }' in MainWindow INSTEAD of public static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosaur>(); ? AND where would static MainWindow() { Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosuar>(); } be inserted? In the class? This throws an error wherever I put it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait until tomorrow to look at your example. Wherever I put static MainWindow() { Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosuar>(); }  in the Dinosaur.cs class it throws errors. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35216/discussion-between-viv-and-zetar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok having looked at your source could get a solution for your use-case. I do suggest checking into MVVM properly.As it stands right now, Your project goes against MVVM in quite a few areas as I mentioned in chat.

Putting that aside with your current implementation to get the `Dinosaurs` list to be in sync with the `ActiveDinosaurList` View, these are the changes I made:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

1) Switch `Dinosaurs` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` and a property. Such as

```
public static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosaur>();
```

to

```
public static ObservableCollection<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs { get; set; }
```

2) Add a static constructor to the `MainWindow` class to initialize the `Dinosaurs` property

```
static MainWindow() {
  Dinosaurs = new ObservableCollection<Dinosaur>();
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

3) Switch the `Dinosaurs` property to be a pass-thru to the static property in `MainWindow` and remove the backing collection. Such as

```
private ObservableCollection<Dinosaur> _dinoList = new ObservableCollection<Dinosaur>();
public ObservableCollection<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs
{
   get { return _dinoList; }
   set { _dinoList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Dinosaurs"); }
}
```

to

```
public ObservableCollection<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs {
  get {
    return MainWindow.Dinosaurs;
  }
}
```

4) Finally add a hook to listen to `CollectionChanged` on `MainWindow.Dinosaurs` from `ViewModel` and `RaisePropertyChanged` on it's `Dinosaurs` property.

so switch:

```
public ViewModel()
{
   this.Dinosaurs = new ObservableCollection<Dinosaur>();
   for(int i = 0; i < MainWindow.Dinosaurs.Count; i++)
     this.Dinosaurs.Add(new Dinosaur()
      {
         PersonalName = MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].PersonalName,
         Specie = MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Specie,
         Health =  MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Health,
         State =  MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].State
      });
}
```

to

```
public ViewModel() {
  MainWindow.Dinosaurs.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => RaisePropertyChanged("Dinosaurs");
}
```

That's it. Running your simulation now, When I forwarded the time, I could see the Status on the ActiveDinosaurs list getting updated fine.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your bindings use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

So your label would look like this: `<Label Name="DinosaurStatus" Margin="0,0,0,-8" Content="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource DinoStatusConverter} UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`.

Comment: I've added   <Label Name="DinosaurStatus" Margin="0,0,0,-8" Content="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource DinoStatusConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/> (note added comma) but it's still not updating correctly.

Comment: OP's issue has nothing to do with `UpdateSourceTrigger` here.

Comment: @Viv: Yeah, I wasn't sure about that. I had the same problem and adding `UpdateSourceTrigger` fixed it.